# gcc source: angle bracket behind specifier - is this plain C?

Tags: gcc

I started digging into the Source code of GCC and stumbled upon the following line:

```
ridpointers = ggc_cleared_vec_alloc<tree> ((int) RID_MAX);
```

https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/c/c-parser.c#L125

The file is called *c-parser.c* so I assumed it to be plain C code. But I have never seen angle brackets used like this. What do they mean in this context, and is this still plain C code or Objective-C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No that's not C, that's C++.

GCC is compiled using the C++ compiler since a few years back, apparently even though they have still kept the old file names.